# I convert file to GTFS（using transitfeed）and I haven't create shape.txt

Tags: python, general-transit-feed-specification

I using transitfeed by python to convert my file to GTFS

but I haven't connect shape.txt and the trip.txt

and it show

> [the shapes with the following shape_ids aren't used by any trips：1]